# transform array of strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings (strings have an object shape). I would like to convert it to an array of objects.
I tried with JSON.parse but am not successful.

```
let a=["{Axis:1,Value:-74}", "{Axis:2,Value:7}", "{Axis:3,Value:-47}", "{Axis:4,Value:85}"]

Desired result
a=[{Axis:1,Value:-74}, {Axis:2,Value:7}, {Axis:3,Value:-47}, {Axis:4,Value:85}]
```

Comment: `const newArr = a.map(el => JSON.parse(el))`

Comment: Where did you get this data from? Are the objects always with these two properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could evaluate the objects, because they are not formatted as JSON standard.

```js
let a = ["{Axis:1,Value:-74}", "{Axis:2,Value:7}", "{Axis:3,Value:-47}", "{Axis:4,Value:85}"],
    result = a.map(s => eval(`(${s})`));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

The first is that you won't be able to call `JSON.parse` on `a` because `JSON.parse` can only parse strings containing properly formatted `JSON`.

The second issue is that the strings in your array are not properly formatted JSON.

The solution for this would be to make the strings properly formatted JSON, as follows:

```
let a=['{"Axis":1,"Value":-74}", '{"Axis":2,Value:7}', '{"Axis":3,"Value":-47}', '{"Axis":4,"Value":85}'];
```

Then to create an array of those objects, you'll have to use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), as follows:

```
a = a.map(e => JSON.parse(e));
```